# how to read data from a file in shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, sh

I have two shell script files **test1.sh and test2.sh** . I have another file called **translogs.txt**.
Now I need to copy the values of two variables in test1.sh to translog.txt and the same variables need to be copied to the corresponding values in **test2.sh**.

**test1.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
ONE="000012"
TIME="2013-02-19 15:31:06"
echo -e "$ONE\n$TIME">translog.txt;
```

**translog.txt**

```
ONE="000012"
TIME="2013-02-19 15:31:06"
```

But here in **test2.sh**, I want the same value as in translog.txt to the corresponding variable like ONE and TIME should have the same value as in translog.txt

**test2.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
ONE="000012"
TIME="2013-02-19 15:31:06"
```

Comment: Are those the only contents of **translog.txt**?

Comment: @Dennis Yes they are the only contents

Answer (score 1):

If you want the contents of *translog.txt* to actually look like in your example and you don't mind switching from dash to bash, you can use `source` (see **Shell Builtin Commands** in [man bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)) to simply execute the contents of *translog.txt* in the current shell.

#### test1.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
ONE="000012"
TIME="2013-02-19 15:31:06"
echo -e "ONE=\"$ONE\"\nTIME=\"$TIME\"">translog.txt;
```

#### test2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
source translog.txt
echo "ONE:  $ONE"
echo "TIME: $TIME"
```

#### Test

```
$ ./test1.sh
$ cat translog.txt 
ONE="000012"
TIME="2013-02-19 15:31:06"
$ ./test2.sh
ONE:  000012
TIME: 2013-02-19 15:31:06
```